# Adding random product listing for categories

Tags: collection, product-list, product-collection, sorting, random

How i can add a new option in the drop down product listing in category layout?
I saw a lot of threads which customize `template\catalog\product\list.phtml`
But i think adding a new dropdown option is better and the dropdown will still be valuable...

Comment: what mean by dropdown? ]

Comment: "Sort by: price / position / name" sorry my theme has a dropdown there... I dont remember how it looks in default theme :P

Answer (score 1):

### The following simple but unperformant solution should work

In your layout, add the custom order like this:

```
<reference name="product_list_toolbar">
    <action method="addOrderToAvailableOrders" translate="label">
        <code>RAND()</code>
        <label>Random</label>
    </action>
</reference>
```

(in `catalog_category_default`, `catalog_category_layered` or in the custom layout update configuration for a single category)

The problem with this is, that the resulting `ORDER BY RAND()` query is very slow, especially for big categories. A performant solution would need custom preparation of the collection and is not integrated so easily.

> You can read more about random product collection performance on my blog: http://www.schmengler-se.de/en/2015/09/show-random-products-in-magento-you-are-doing-it-wrong/

### A different approach

You could add a column "random_sort" to the product index tables and use a cronjob to update it with new random numbers regularly (e.g. every few minutes or every hour). Then you can use the XML snippet from above and replace `RAND()` with `random_sort`. As a positive side effect, even pagination in the random order will work, without getting duplicates. At least until the random numbers are regenerated.

Answer (score 0):

@Alexandros some help to ans

you can get the used category from:

```
$category = Mage::registry('category') or Mage::registry('current_category')
```

To do so, you want to implement an observer listening on `catalog_block_product_list_collection` and instead of joining and filtering for stock options, you 
add a category filter: `addCategoryFilter` based on the registry entry.

Comment: You are talking like chinese to me :)

Comment: NO Sir  i speak only English